# Error when showing Logistic Regression results

Tags: tuples, jupyter

When I try to run a logistic regression in Jupyter notebooks, I get the following error:

---

```
model=LogisticRegression()
scoring='accuracy'
results = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
print("Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)") % (results.mean(), results.std())
```

---

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were just missing the most outer wrapping parens. Try this.

```
print(("Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)") % (results.mean(), results.std()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this naive question.

Comment: Np :), happens to us all.